# MySQL InnoDB thousand tables cannot start service

Tags: mysql

I have problem with MySQL Database with thousand tables

1. Folder Database size 66 GB with 16.000 tables can start service
   normally
2. When database size with 180 GB with 66.000 tables **cannot
   start service**

this is my.ini

```
[client]
port=3306
[mysql]
no-beep
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=E:/DataMySQLServer/Data
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="WIN-PN6P4KVFP6B.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="WIN-PN6P4KVFP6B-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="WIN-PN6P4KVFP6B.err"
server-id=1
secure-file-priv="E:/DataMySQLServer/Uploads"
max_connections=151
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=70000
tmp_table_size=60M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=111M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=9
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=4M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=70000
query_cache_type=0
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

mysql.error

```
2018-02-06T14:13:31.328373Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT 
value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server 
option (see documentation for more details).
2018-02-06T14:13:31.338701Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' 
and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. 
They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-02-06T14:13:31.343938Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 
5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.21-log) starting as process 3408 ...
2018-02-06T14:13:31.524790Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use 
Windows interlocked functions
2018-02-06T14:13:31.525769Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-02-06T14:13:31.526446Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() 
are used for memory barrier
2018-02-06T14:13:31.526917Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 
 1.2.3
2018-02-06T14:13:31.538396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-02-06T14:13:31.554578Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 
instructions
2018-02-06T14:13:31.557844Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total 
size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2018-02-06T14:13:31.703384Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of 
buffer pool
2018-02-06T14:13:31.884100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format 
is Barracuda.
```

Why cannot start service? please help...

note my.ini file above we change some rows like `table_open_cache=70000`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G` and `open_files_limit=70000`

Comment: 66000 tables? You have a database dealing with 66000 different entities? I'm curious: what is this database about? If I'd put all data of a company in relational tables (products, product groups, product details, suppliers, countries, brands, companies, contracts, addresses, delivery conditions, taxes, employees, salary levels, job shifts, maybe even the building, the rooms, ...) I think these may add up to, say, three or four thousand entities, but 66000??? What is it you are managing in your database? I must admit I'm stunned.

Comment: thank you for your response, we have  solved the problem. We have split our table into different entities because all process is processed in one entity and not related to other entities. We have to do that because partitioning in mysql only 8.000 partitions/table (we have 18.000 entities). If we insert data into one table, too many rows data will be inserted, will be slow. we solve the problem with change `[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total 
size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M` into 8GB, and wait untill all process done, 12 minutes all process done (wait and patient)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section

```
#myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G  # lead with # for default until u know what u need
table_open_cache=50000  # from 70000 until you are stable
```

with table_definition_cache=1400, you should survive with open_files_limit=70000
because 50000 + 1400 = < 70000.

Comment: thank you for your response, we have solved the problem. We have split our table into different entities because all process is processed in one entity and not related to other entities. We have to do that because partitioning in mysql only 8.000 partitions/table (we have 18.000 entities). If we insert data into one table, too many rows data will be inserted, will be slow. we solve the problem with change [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M into 8GB, and wait untill all process done, 12 minutes all process done (wait and patient)